# Anyone booted ecos with u-boot?

Tags: porting, u-boot, rtos, ecos

I need to port ecos on new platform board with u-boot.
Everywhere I am able to find Porting guide for ecos with **redboot**.
Did anyone booted ecos with u-boot?
I got some link which tells it's possible to boot ecos with u-boot?
https://sourceware.org/ml/ecos-discuss/2010-06/msg00038.html
But I am not able to find any document regarding that.

I tried following following procedure to boot ecos with u-boot

- compiled ecos 3.0
- ecosconfig new
- ecosconfig tree
- make
- cross compiled and generated sample hello_world elf linking library
     generated in previous make.
- Powered on the board and stopped at u-boot(prebuilt u-boot already in
  flash)
- Transferred  hello_world to a load_addr(entry point address of RAM) through tftp
- bootelf load_addr

But it got hanged as follows,

```
bootelf 0x820000bc
Loading .rom_vectors @ 0x82000000 (204 bytes)
Loading .text @ 0x820000cc (224132 bytes)
```

**EDIT :**

```
When I try loading at address 0x81000000 It proceed further as follows,

bootelf 0x81000000
Loading .rom_vectors @ 0x82000000 (204 bytes)
Loading .text @ 0x820000cc (207960 bytes)
Loading .rodata @ 0x82032d28 (7296 bytes)
Loading .data @ 0x820349a8 (2544 bytes)
Loading .ctors @ 0x82035398 (80 bytes)
Loading .dtors @ 0x820353e8 (56 bytes)
Loading .devtab @ 0x82035420 (608 bytes)
Clearing .sbss @ 0x82035680 (276 bytes)
Clearing .bss @ 0x82035798 (313052 bytes)
## Starting application at 0x820000bc ...
```

But hangs after the above line. My ELF file size is around 1.9 MB. Will it make a problem?

Note: RAM size - 8 MB (0x80000000 - 0x88000000)

Comment: There are perhaps compelling reasons to stick with RedBoot: https://sourceware.org/ml/ecos-discuss/2010-06/msg00040.html

Comment: @Clifford it is the requirement we need to boot ecos with u-boot.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be hard.  If you have an ELF file, bootelf will boot it.

Comment: We tried booting with bootelf command but its gets hung. Edited my question with some more details.

Comment: What version of U-Boot is on the board?  There have been some bootelf related fixes in the last year or so.  You can also test by using the U-Boot hello_world as an ELF to ensure that part is working correctly.

Comment: U boot version on the board is - U-Boot 1.1.4 
Yes, I tried U boot standalone application (hello_world). Its working fine.

Comment: u-boot> bootelf 0x80000000
Loading .text @ 0x80200000 (448 bytes)
Loading .reginfo @ 0x802001c0 (24 bytes)
Loading .rodata.str1.4 @ 0x802001d8 (84 bytes)
Loading .got @ 0x80200230 (44 bytes)
## Starting application at 0x80200000 ...
Example expects ABI version 2
Actual U-Boot ABI version 2
Hello World

## Application terminated, rc = 0x0

Comment: And are you sure eCos is otherwise fine?  With your additional log U-Boot is transferring control over to eCos at that point.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I am able to boot eCos with u-boot. after I loaded at proper LOAD_ADDRESS (0x8000000).